# CSS combine border settings into one line

Tags: css

I can't think of how to combine these into one line..

```
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;   
border-top: 10px solid #000;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: your requirement is **just for fun**.

Comment: Yes this is an arrow. It's for fun yes, for my business website to make money which is fun!

Comment: The linked question seems to answer your question: you cannot do this with plain CSS. However, you could implement this in your working files using SASS (http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins). Take a look at the part regarding mixins with arguments.

Comment: to make money, with the current version it is still OK, it's just **a little longer**, you can rewrite it to make it maintain better **but** the one-line solution is impossible, one-line solution is also harder to maintain.

Comment: I want to make an arrow that I can flip back and forth with jquery from pointing down to pointing up

Comment: A common way to deal with states is to define multiple classes. For example, if your arrow element has class `.arrow` and by default points up, you could define an additional class `.down` with the downwards-pointing styles. To toggle up/down, just use jQuery's `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods with `.down`.

Answer (score 0):

One line you cant! But you can do this:

```
border: 10px solid transparent;
border-top-color:#000;
```

Take care about border-bottom because because will be overridden

Comment: What about `border-bottom`? it will be overridden to `10px solid transparent` while we don't know if it should be so.

Comment: Yes you are right! I just try to minimize max as I can.